# Casting giving 'identifier expected' error even though I am respecting dot operator precedence (C#)

Tags: c#, casting, operator-precedence, identifier, dot-operator

Originally my code was:

```
spreadRight = equipmentSlots[5].(EquippableItem)Item.DamageVariance;
```

However this threw errors and I learned about the dot operator having higher precedence than casting. So I redid it as:

```
spreadRight = equipmentSlots[5].((EquippableItem)Item).DamageVariance;
```

However, it is still giving me 'identifier expected' error. Is it still a problem with operator precedence, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Include the initialization of equipmentSlots and spreadRight in your snippets to help us debug your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to cast `Item` property of element from `equipmentSlots` collection to `EquippableItem`, you should change your code like this:

```
spreadRight = ((EquippableItem)equipmentSlots[5].Item).DamageVariance;
```